# Sorting numbers in the list without using sort command

Tags: matlab, sorting, numbers

I'm trying to sort the numbers in the list without using sort command in Matlab. I couldn't find what's wrong with my code.

Here is what I tried:

```
clc
A= [1 2 4 0 0 8]
B=[]
for i=1:length(A)
    indx=find(A==min(A))
    for j=1:length(indx)
        B(i)=A(indx(j))
    end
    A(indx(1):indx(length(indx)))=[]
    B
end
```

Results are:

```
    B =

 0     1     2     4     8


indx =

1×0 empty double row vector

Index exceeds the number of array elements (0).
```

The expected value for B is

```
B =

    0     0     1     2     4     8
```

Comment: What is your error? What does that error tell you about the number of iterations you're doing on the loop? Why is that happening? (Hint: how many elements do you remove from `A` on each iteration?)

Comment: What happens here is, in the second for B(1)=A(index(1)) and B(1)= A(index(2)). What I want is B(2)= A(index(2))

Comment: Not the source of your error, but what is this? `A(indx(1):indx(length(indx)))`? That takes all elements between the first and last matches, rather than only the matches. Why not just `A(indx)`? Also, `indx(length(indx))` is the same as `indx(end)` (but slower).

Comment: @fyec, you're right, that's one of the problems. In order to fix this, you need to increment `B(i)` for each iteration of `j`. So maybe `B(i+j-1) = A(indx(j))`? But that's not what's giving you the error message.

Comment: The error comes from the line that @CrisLuengo mentioned where you remove multiple matches, but still iterate over the original length of `A`. You just run out of elements to match, and when `indx == []`, then `indx(1)` doesn't exist. To fix this, I'd change your `for i...` loop to a `while ~isempty(A)`, which continues to loop only as long as `A` has elements left to sort.

Answer (score 0):

This one corrects your code:

```
A= [1 2 4 0 0 8];
L=length(A);
B=zeros(1,L);
k=1;
for i=1:L
    indx=find(A==min(A));
    for j=1:length(indx)
        B(k)=A(indx(j));
        k=k+1;
    end
    A(indx)=[];
    B
end
```

The problem in your code is that any time after finding the minimum, you overwrite them on current data on `B` (since in the second `for` you always start from index 1)